# Запись видео на iphone при заблокированном телефоне

Tags: ios, swift

Всем привет. Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?
Необходимо, чтобы Iphone сам записывал видео раз в час, по 30 секунд. Возможно ли это при заблокированном телефоне?
Я начал с AVCaptureSession, затем нашел методы по записи видеофайла. Но не могу понять как запустить камеру, какой именно метод за это отвечает.

Если расскажите логику, буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись видео и и съёмка фото в background-режиме (в том числе и при заблокированном телефоне) запрещена на iOS. Подтверждение этому можно найти, например, в документации к символу AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReasonVideoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground.